# How to pass ENV arguments in my Dockerfile when using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml that has a section:

```
myservice:
  env_file:
    - myvars.env
```

My env variable file has:

```
myvars.env:
SOME_VAL=123
```

And then in my Dockerfile I have this:

```
..
RUN echo "some_val ${SOME_VAL}"
ENTRYPOINT bash ${APP_BASE}/run.sh SOME_VAL=${SOME_VAL}
```

When I run docker-compose up, the value of some_val is empty.

1. Why is SOME_VAL not accessible in my dockerfile?
2. How do I pass the env variable SOME_VAL to my run.sh script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [declare the variable with `ENV` in the `Dockerfile` before using it](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/#arg-and-env-availability):

> ENV variables are also available during the build, as soon as you introduce them with an ENV instruction.

**`Dockerfile`**

```
ENV SOME_VAL
RUN echo "some_val ${SOME_VAL}"
ENTRYPOINT bash ${APP_BASE}/run.sh SOME_VAL=${SOME_VAL}
```

Comment: if I just put ```ENV SOME_VAL``` I get an error saying "ENV must have two arguments"

Comment: @Blankman you can do `ENV SOME_VAL=`.  I remember not needing the `=` but something must have changed in an update.

Answer (score 0):

When you `docker-compose build` an image, it only considers the [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) sections of the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Nothing else from any other part of the file is considered.  `environment:` and `env_file:` settings aren't available, nor are `volumes:` nor `networks:`.  The only way to pass settings in is through the Dockerfile `ARG` and the corresponding Compose `args:` settings, and even then, you only want to use this for things you'd "compile in" to the image.

Conveniently, shell scripts can directly access environment variables already, so you don't need to do anything at all; just use the variable.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# run.sh

echo "SOME_VAL is $SOME_VAL"
```

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /app
COPY run.sh .
# RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  echoer:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - my_vars.env
    # environment:
    #   SOME_VAL: foo
```

Comment: but SOME_VAL is defined in an external file myvars.env

Comment: Setting `env_file: [myvars.env]` will load it at the same time and in the same way as putting it inline in `environment:`.  The process inside the container can't tell the difference.